# memory efficient way to stack array in python

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, memory-efficient

there are large arrays, and I want to read them and stack them, like:

```
>>> x=npy.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
>>> y=npy.arange(10,20).reshape(5,2)
>>> npy.append(x,y)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])

>>> z.reshape(2,x.shape[0],x.shape[1])
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9]],

       [[10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17],
        [18, 19]]])
```

but the result will big and bigger and finally program stop with out_of_memory.
the code is:

```
for i in range(1, days+1):
    with rasterio.open(directory+"B04_"+str(i)+".jp2") as dataset:
        band_4=dataset.read()[0]

    with rasterio.open(directory+"B08_"+str(i)+".jp2") as dataset:
        band_8=dataset.read()[0]

    _=(band_8- band_4) / (band_8+ band_4+0.0000001)
    ndvi=npy.append(ndvi, ـ )

ndvi=ndvi.reshape(days ,band_8.shape[0],band_8.shape[1])
```

what is the most memory efficient way to read and append array?

Comment: How many arrays and what size?

Comment: `y=npy.arange(20).reshape(5,2)` from your example raises an error.

Comment: The use of `npy.append` like this is not ideal, speedwise, but shouldn't affect the space usage.  Sooner or later, as you add more files, you'll hit a memory error.  At some point the resulting array will be bigger than your RAM can hold.  There are other recent SO questions about concatenating arrays.

Comment: @saintsfan342000 done.

Comment: @hpaulj ndvi size pass from 32gb

Answer (score 0):

Try Dask (http://dask.pydata.org/) it should solve your problem. This library allows to put some part of your data on disk if it's to big to fit in memory.

Comment: this answer seems more suited as a comment

Comment: test it but, dose not help to me.